# Cakephp unexpected syntax error in toolbarComponent line 182

Tags: php, cakephp

Browser Error: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cakePHP/cakeBlog/cakephp/plugins/DebugKit/Controller/Component/ToolbarComponent.php on line 182

```
Line 181-191
public function implementedEvents() {
    $before = function ($name) {
        return function () use ($name) {
            DebugTimer::start($name, __d('debug_kit', $name));
        };
    };
    $after = function ($name) {
        return function () use ($name) {
            DebugTimer::stop($name);
        };
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your PHP Version to 5.3.0 or greater...

Because DebugKit plugin is using [Anonymous Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) which are not supported for 5.2 and lower versions.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check your PHP version?
It seems like you need 5.3+